# Settings opens the window but is not seen

Tags: settings

Clicking on the Settings icon opens the specific window, but it does not appear on the screen. You can only see it if I right click on the icon. I tried to give various commands from the terminal without result.
I just installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on an Asus laptop.
The installed version is up to date, what can I do?

Comment: I have a similar problem. The windows of settings does not open at all!